# NextJS 13: Refetch data on each route change in layout component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I need to fetch some navigation items from our CMS. It is working as planned and i get the correct route structure with the active page on load. But when I switch to another route, it doesn't refetch the navigation pages.

The fetch call is done in my headernavigation.tsx used in my layout.tsx. I set the revalidate option to 'no-store', but it had no effect, since the router is not refreshed.

My folder structure looks like this:

- src

  - app

    - page.tsx
    - layout.tsx
    - navigation

      - headernavigation.tsx

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your code and folder structure?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar i added the folder structure